# Issue with query waypoints plugin basic example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

for some reason I can't get the basic example from [waypoints plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started) working. Any idea what is wrong? Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZA8bd/2/

CSS

```
  .block1 {
    margin-top:30px;
   width: 400px;
   background: red;
height: 800px;
}

.block2 {
    margin-top:30px;
   width: 400px;
   background: green;
height: 800px;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
```

JS

```
$('.block2').waypoint(function() {
  notify('100 pixels from the top');
}, { offset: 100 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine except the javascript is not able to look up for notify() function.
Using alert() instead works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to define `notify` variable that will handle message:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZA8bd/3/